# Text field input won't display upon click

Tags: jquery, textfield

The basic idea is when a user enters their name into a field then clicks a button, a string "Hi [name] etc" displays back to them.

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function sayHi(){
          var visitor_name_input = document.getElementByID("#visitor_name_input");
          var introduction = document.getElementByClass(".introduction");
          var name = visitor_name_input.value;
          introduction.value = "Hi there, " + name + "!"
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<p id="greeting">
            <input type="text" id="visitor_name_input" placeholder="what's your name?">
            <input type="image" class="skip-btn" onclick="sayHi()" src="skipbtn.png" height="50px"/></a>
            <input type="image" class="enter-btn" onclick = "sayHi()" src="enterbtn1.png" height="50px" />
         </p>

    <div class="introduction">

    </div>
```

I hope I have done an okay job asking this question. I am new here and new to web dev.  I'm wondering why my jQuery doesn't work.  Thank you thank you so much for any insights into this!!

UPDATE: Here's the code that finally worked (you guys ROCK, thank you!)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.skip-btn, .enter-btn').on('click', function(){
      var visitor_name_input = $("#visitor_name_input");
      var introduction = $(".introduction");
      var name = visitor_name_input.val();
      $(introduction).text("Hi " + name + ", I'm Jenny.  I create user experiences on the web.  Scroll down to see my resume.");
 });
});
```

Next I just have to figure out how to trigger some horizontal parallax when they scroll ^_^  (That's a whole other post, of course!!)

I really can't thank you guys enough as I am 100% self-taught at what little that I have managed to grasp so far :)

Comment: `introduction` is a div and it does not have a `value` attribute. try using `introduction.innerText = 'Hi there, ' + name + '!'`  try this jsfiddle for a much cleaner code. http://jsfiddle.net/53bgwtxu/

Comment: were you able to solve your issue @JennyChisnell ?

Comment: Hi Sushil thank you, I figured out a workable solution based on the comments received, see update above!

Comment: good job @JennyChisnell

Answer (score 2):

you are mixing `JQuery` and `Javascript` together.

since you're already using `JQuery` you can update your js code like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.skip-btn, .enter-btn').on('click', function() {
         var visitor_name_input = $("#visitor_name_input");
         var introduction = $(".introduction");
         var name = visitor_name_input.val();
         $(introduction).text("Hi there, " + name + "!");
     });
 });
```

where `.skip-btn, .enter-btn` are the `classes` on your `buttons`. you can also use `id's` if you want to.

also `introduction` is a `div` and it does not have a `value` attribute. so it won't work for you. try using `innerText` if you're using plain javascript or `.text()` if you're using JQuery.

here's a working [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/53bgwtxu/1/) for the same. hope this helps.

Comment: I tried all the suggestions I got, and this is the one that worked for me!

Comment: thanks @JennyChisnell. can you please mark this as an answer??

Answer (score 0):

The function should be outside the document ready handler.`onclick` can only access the function in global context.

```js
function sayHi() {
  var visitor_name_input = document.getElementById("visitor_name_input"),
    //                   d should be small letter -^--^-- no need for #  
    introduction = document.getElementsByClassName("introduction"),
    //   getElementsByClass is not valid it should be getElementsByClassName , then there is no need for . here  
    name = visitor_name_input.value;

  introduction[0].innerHTML = "Hi there, " + name + "!";
    //          -^- since you are getting collection of dom objects so you need to use [0] for getting first one. also there is no value attribute for div. You need to innerHTML for setting the html content.
}
```

```html
<p id="greeting">
  <input type="text" id="visitor_name_input" placeholder="what's your name?">
  <input type="image" class="skip-btn" onclick="sayHi()" src="skipbtn.png" height="50px" />

  <input type="image" class="enter-btn" onclick="sayHi()" src="enterbtn1.png" height="50px" />
</p>

<div class="introduction">

</div>
```

**Update :** 
You were tagged jQuery you can make it more simple

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.skip-btn,.enter-btn').click(function() {
    var visitor_name_input = $("#visitor_name_input"),
      introduction = $(".introduction"),
      name = visitor_name_input.val();
    // get input value using val()

    introduction.html("Hi there, " + name + "!");
    // setting html content inside div using html(), you can use text() for setting text content

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="greeting">
  <input type="text" id="visitor_name_input" placeholder="what's your name?">
  <input type="image" class="skip-btn" src="skipbtn.png" height="50px" />
  <input type="image" class="enter-btn" src="enterbtn1.png" height="50px" />
</p>

<div class="introduction">

</div>
```

Comment: how is `document.getElementByID("#visitor_name_input");` going to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `document.getElementByClass`.

You probably meant `document.getElementsByClassName` which returns a nodeList not a individual element.

if you wanted the 1st item that matches the class:

```
var introduction = document.getElementsByClassName("introduction")[0];
```

You also are confusing jQuery id selector with the function to return the elementbyid.

There is no need for the # infront of the id.

```
var visitor_name_input = document.getElementById("visitor_name_input")
```